# Storing file information in a database

Tags: mysql, file, hosting, storage, quota

I am building a file hosting site and would like to keep track of users file quota ( Each user is only allowed 2gb of file storage). Could anyone explain how I could store file name, type and importantly size of all files uploaded by a user in a mysql database. And is it possible to calculate using php script or MySQL when users exceed limit, display a message and reject any further uploads until files have been deleted by them to reduce quota?

I am fairly new to mySQl and would really appreciate some simple guides on how to achieve this.

Thanks

R

Comment: You say you're fairly new to MySQL. Do you know how to create tables and define columns? If you haven't learned that yet, you should read something on it.

Comment: What platform are you running on? (I'm guessing a Unix/Linux variant or some kind?)

Answer (score 1):

> ...is it possible to calculate using
>   php script or MySQL when users exceed
>   limit, display a message and reject
>   any further uploads until files have
>   been deleted by them to reduce quota?

### Short Answer

Yes.

### Long Answer

Yes but it will take some coding.

I recommend:

- Use PHP for the file-handling side of things
- Store information about the files in your MySQL database

You definitely can store the file name, file type and size of each file in your database.

You can use this data to ensure that a user has quota remaining, and warn / block them when they try to upload files once they've reached their quota.

If you're new to MySQL / PHP, then this sounds like a great project to get you started with both.

I recommend the Tizag tutorials: [PHP / MySQL](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/).

Once you've covered the basics, please read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Edit: to find the size of a file with PHP, use [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php).

Comment: Hi Yes I do know how to create tables columns and so on.. Its just that im stuck on how to calculate a files size in a database

Comment: You calculate the file size in php and store the size as an int in MySQL

Comment: Updated answer with a link to the PHP function used to find a file's size.